# Pandas header all letters of alphabet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is it possible to fill a dataframe I have in pandas with as many letters of the alphabet as I have columns? For example if I get the amount of columns and there are 50, I would have to fill every column header until "AX".

```
nrcolumns=len(df.columns)
```

The fact is that I haven't found a way to pd.read_excel with the headers taken from the column names in excel.

Thanks

Comment: Eh, I really don't think this is an exact duplicate of that question. this will be `pandas` specific and I see this having value for people who use pandas alongside Excel.

Comment: Thanks MattR, I also don't really see how the answer from that question (give a number for row and column and get excel row and column output) can help with mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `string`

```
import string
l=list(string.ascii_uppercase)
b=l+[x+y for x in l for y in l]
b[50-1]
Out[1240]: 'AX'
```

Comment: Thanks! very helpful